# (Milne CFT p. 36) Showing an $A$-module in an exact sequence is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I am currently working on the following proof from Milne's Class Field Theory.

Here $K$ is a nonarchimedean local field, $A$ its valuation ring $A = \{\alpha \in K: | \alpha| \leq 1\}$. So $A$ is a DVR and its maximal ideal $\mathcal{m} = \{ \alpha \in A: | \alpha| < 1\}$ is generated by some prime element $\pi$. $A/ (\pi)$ is a finite field with $q$ elements.

[image]

The highlighted text is the only part that is not clear to me. I can see that $M_n/M_1 \simeq M_{n-1}$ by exactness, and by induction we may even assume that $M_1$ and $M_{n-1}$ are cyclic. $M_n$ decomposes into a direct sum of cyclic modules (since $A$ is a PID with a unique prime element), but why is it necessary that $M_n$ is cyclic? I feel like I am missing something very obvious and I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Write $M_n\simeq A/(\pi^{k_1})\oplus A/(\pi^{k_2})\oplus\cdots$ with $k_j\ge 1$. Then $$M_1 \simeq \{(a_1\pi^{k_1-1},a_2\pi^{k_2 -1}, \cdots)\mid a_j\in A/(\pi)\}.$$ Agree? OK?

Comment: @peterag Oh, I see it!  Thank you!

Comment: well, it's the idea. I see my notation was crummy ( namely $a_j \in A/(\pi)$)

Comment: @peterag Right it explains everything. What about thisone : let $M_\infty = \{ x \in M, \exists n, \pi^n x = 0\}$. If it is non-trivial try to find some $y \in M_\infty, \not \in \pi M$, $l = \min \{ l, \pi^l y = 0\}$, if it exists and $M_\infty \supsetneq A y$ we have $|M_1| > q$. If such a $y$ doesn't exist then $M_\infty$ contains a sequence $z_0 = 0, z_1 \ne 0, z_n = \pi z_{n+1}$ thus $N=\lim_{n \to \infty} A z_n$ is isomorphic to $Frac(A)/A$ and if $M_\infty \supsetneq N$ then $|M_1| > q$. Thus $|M_1|=q$ means $M_\infty \cong A/(\pi^l)$ or $M_\infty \cong Frac(A)/A$

Comment: @reuns I think ok... You are doing away with the hypothesis that multiplication by $\pi$ is onto (for $y$ to have a chance of existing)?